# Jest act wrapper issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, warnings

This is my JEST test case. I wrapped my state changing actions into `act`. But it doesn't help.

```js
  it('ListInput add item', done => {
    const valueTyped = '123.1.1.1';
    const formItemDataPath = ['proxy', 'rules', 'excludedAddresses'];
    let listInputInternalInput;
    let listInputAddItemButton;
    let c;
    let formValue;

    const handleFormChange = v => {
      formValue = v;
    };

    act(() => {
      const ListInputForm = () => {
        return (
          <div>
            <BasicForm initialValue={clone(bondingFormData)} onChange={handleFormChange}>
              <BasicFormItem name={formItemDataPath} label={'listInput'}>
                <ListInput data-testid='listInput' />
              </BasicFormItem>
            </BasicForm>
          </div>
        );
      };
      const { container } = render(<ListInputForm />);
      c = container;
    });

    listInputInternalInput = c!.querySelector('Input');
    listInputAddItemButton = c!.querySelector('[type=button]');

    act(() => {
      fireEvent.change(listInputInternalInput, { target: { value: valueTyped } });
      fireEvent.click(listInputAddItemButton);
    });

    //
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(getProperty(formValue!, formItemDataPath)).toEqual([
        ...getProperty(bondingFormData, formItemDataPath),
        valueTyped,
      ]);
      done();
    }, 1000);
  });
```

I still see a warning message:

```
      at recipe (.../BasicForm.tsx:29:17)
  console.error
    Warning: An update to BasicForm inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
    
    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
        at BasicForm (.../BasicForm.tsx:65:11)
        at div
        at ListInputForm
```

Test passes now, but fails if I remove `setTimeout`.
So I want 2 things: to get rid of warning and setTimeout.
Any ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: @mandy8055 It helped with setTimeout, but not with the warning. Thanks

Comment: The warning is probably caused by `fireEvent.click(listInputAddItemButton);`. If I remove this line the warning disappears. But I still cannot get what's wrong with the line, or how to replace it

Comment: I have added it as my answer. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the warning message and `setTimeout`, you can try using `async/await` along with the ***[`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)*** function which will ensure that all state updates are properly wrapped within `act()`. Below is the code for the same:

```js
it('ListInput add item', async () => {
  // ...Rest of code
  await act(async () => {
     // ...
  });

  // ...

  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.change(listInputInternalInput, { target: { value: valueTyped } });
    fireEvent.click(listInputAddItemButton);
  });

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getProperty(formValue!, formItemDataPath)).toEqual([
      ...getProperty(bondingFormData, formItemDataPath),
      valueTyped,
    ]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Couldn't get rid of the warning, unfortunately. But it definetely helped with timeout